# Create a Solr Index using Lucene IndexWriter

Tags: solr, lucene.net, solrnet, lucene

I need to index vast amounts of content in extremely short order, I have tried various techniques using Solrnet/solr using threading and TPL, however the speeds leave a lot to be desired. Hence considering a move to using Lucene.net index writer to create an index (preliminarily I see almost an order of magnitude of speed improvement) . Any "gotchas"  to be aware of?

I am not too sure if:
1. Trie based Numeric Range query would continue to be available for query via Solr. ( I am using NumericFields in Lucene)?
2.  Faceting etc. would continue to be available ?

Anything else I need to watch out for?

Comment: There probably is something to do to improve indexing throughput with Solr... what mergeFactor do you use? how often do you commit? what is you ramBufferSizeMB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [Scaling Lucene and Solr](http://searchhub.org/2009/09/02/scaling-lucene-and-solr/) about improving run times.

If you decide to go with Lucene:

- You need a unique id field for the index to be a valid Solr index.
- The schema must match the Solr schema.
- The Lucene version must be the same as in Solr.
- I think the range query and faceting will be available, as long as you index the respective fields according to the requirements in Solr, and use the same analyzers.

Comment: Thanks Yuval, my challenge is that I am using Lucene.net (hence limited to 2.9). I am finding the NumericField in Lucene is causing issues in Solr.

Comment: The link is dead now.

Comment: Hey @Neth, fixed the link.